# How to connect dual brushless motors to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm planning on making a Force Feed Back racing wheel with arduino.Saw a lot of tutorials but it uses brushed DC motors ,couldn't find how to connect dual brushless motor for force feed back.

This the motor I want to use : 
http://www.dx.com/p/chrgm25bl2418-dc-brushless-motor-with-built-in-drive-24v-12v-470930#.WkurLcvhVAg

[image: motor specs]
[image].                       [image].                         [image]

Comment: Your link points to a battery...

Comment: Sorry about the link

Comment: http://www.dx.com/p/chrgm25bl2418-dc-brushless-motor-with-built-in-drive-24v-12v-470930#.WkurLcvhVAg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about haptic motion systems, not Arduino.  This can't be an Arduino question until you've clearly defined what you goal is and verified that you have selected the correct mechanical and driver parts - something that at present it appears you have not, if your goal is "force feedback"

Comment: I want to know if there is any motor controller that could be used to control these motors and could be connected to arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you provide the correct voltage to the VCC and GND pins to power it, and connect the CW/CCW and PWM (and GND of course) to your Arduino - the first to control the direction, and the second to a PWM pin to control the speed.

You can use the FG pin to monitor the speed from the internal hall effect sensor if you want.

Comment: Thanks,is there any motor controller for this..?

Comment: You probably won't get force feedback by this approach.

Comment: It looks like the controller is built in. A bit like a servo.

Comment: So I can connect it to arduino without a motor controller like you said.?

Comment: I repeat my previous comment.